# ipython shell commands error

Tags: shell, command, jupyter-notebook

I tried to use ipython shell command in ipython notebook prefix with '!" but ls was not recognized. Anyone ran into this issue before?

P.S. : the purpose is to filter all files containing name  **edges**

[image: ipython shell command]

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: Hi Jakob, I am using ipython notebook on windows. I tried '!ls *.ipynb` and it works. But command like above wouldn't work. I have looked up and some suggested using **dir** but it seems no good in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange that `!ls` works on windows. The `!` transmits the commands verbatim to the underlying operation system. Therefore, `!ls` shouldn't work on windows. `ls` on the other hand is implemented in IPython and thus should work.

Even though this does not really answer your question. Why don't you simply use a pythonic way to achieve the same? You could use:

```py
files = sorted(filter(lambda x:'edges' in x, os.listdir('.')), key = os.path.getsize)
```

To get the files (and directories) of the current directory filtered after 'edges' and sorted by size.